# Can I create a new folder and import my SQLite into it?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have some SQLite files that should import into App. Notice, One of them should import to unique folder.
For example: I have two files (doc1.sqlite & doc2.sqlite)

```
      /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/doc1/doc1.sqlite
      /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/doc2/doc2.sqlite
```

So, When I create a new folder and import tow files into it, Can I Use them?

Thanks, Omid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can make folders and put the files into it. But make sure you refer the correct databases on your `DatabaseHelper` class

It should be something like this:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        DB_NAME = doc1;

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }
```

Comment: Excuse me @Ajmal, I updated my post. I mean doc1 & doc2 are folder not file and doc1.sqlite insert into doc1 directory

Comment: `DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/doc1/";
DB_NAME = doc1;
DB_PATH_TWO = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/doc2/";
DB_NAME_TWO = doc2;`